# Quoting into Cypher queries using PHP (escaping a string)

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher, neoxygen

I'm using PHP and neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient to build a graph database and looking for a way to escape strings so that I can quote them safely into Cypher queries.
I'm aware of the [documentation on Cypher expressions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html) but I was wondering if perhaps somebody already wrote such an escape function in PHP (or perhaps other languages so that I can port it to PHP)? Perhaps I could get away with using PHP escape functions which already exist for let's say MySQL?

EDIT:
So finally, in case anyone is looking for a way to pass parameters with sendCypherQueries here's an example:

```
$parameters = array(
    'key'=>'example',
);

$client->sendCypherQuery("MERGE (node {key:{key}})", $paramteres);
```

This equals to a Cypher query:

```
MERGE (node {key:'example'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe as potential **"injection"** is possible for all variables that you do not pass as parameters.

So for Cypher and NeoClient, be sure to **ALWAYS** pass your variables as second argument of the `sendCypherQuery` method.

As a side note, in PHP, [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is obsolete since PHP5.5.0, so more than two years ago. 
This is why you would use PDO for eg and pass variables also as query parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I see. I didn't know it's obsolete, indeed I've always used PDO myself. Anyway, I guess I should have turned autocompletion on because I wasn't aware that sendCypherQuery accepts additional parameters. This isn't documented very well on your GitHub page. Could you please give me a hint how to map these parameters inside the query?

Comment: On this page, you have links to 3 articles that I wrote on sitepoint with lot of examples using the client http://neo4j.com/developer/php/

Answer (score 1):

`{key}` syntax is obsolete. Use `$key` instead:

```
$client->sendCypherQuery('MERGE (node { key: $key })', [ 'key' => 'example' ]);
```